# Send ampersand and equal(=) in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, character-encoding, diacritics

I am building a string in jquery und want to submit it by ajax. This is my string:

```
selected_spans  +=  id+'_'+span_data+('=off&');
```

This string is written to a hidden Form field.
After the form is filled out, I am collecting all input data with serialize() and send them with `$.post('assembler-backend.php', data, function (response) {...}`
I have problems sending `0` and `&` to php.

As result, I am getting something like this. Which php function I have to use, to get normal chars (utf8).
The ampersand shall become an `&amp;` for example.
I also want to convert all Umlauts to correct symbols.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery data "eats" objects, so you can do:

```
var data = {foo: "bar&bar"};
```

And jQuery will take care about escaping and all the stuff + you can send multiple attributes an the same time.

Comment: This is no good solution for me. I want to send all all values in one post variable...

Comment: `selected_spans  +=  id+'_'+span_data+('=off&'); data = {varName: selected_spans}`? :)

Comment: In this case, I had two ore more posts again. I am using serialize(), to get one array with all values. Please look above...